# cx_freeze does not include tcl8.6 and tk8.6 folder on macOS when building tkinter app

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, cx-freeze

I am trying to package a tkinter app on macOS. However, cx_freeze does not include the library folder needed. I have not been able to build any app by using the official Python installer package for macOS so I decided to compile my own Python build and link it against the latest tkinter.

My setup:

**Homebrew tkinter installation**

```
brew install tcl-tk
```

**Python environment**

```
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'" MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 pyenv install 3.8.5
pyenv global 3.8.5
python --version
3.8.5
python -m pip install cx_freeze
python -m pip show cx_freeze
[...]Version: 6.2[...]
```

**Python Tkinter Script - app.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame
from os import path, remove, environ
import sys

class mainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False): 
        WorkingDir = path.dirname(sys.executable)
        if sys.platform == "darwin":
            environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = WorkingDir + '/tk8.6/'
            environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = WorkingDir + '/tcl8.6/'
            print(environ['TCL_LIBRARY'])
            print(environ['TK_LIBRARY'])
    else:
        WorkingDir = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))

    root = tk.Tk()
    app = mainWindow()
    root.mainloop()
```

**cx_freeze - setup.py**

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


# MacOS
bdist_mac_options = {'bundle_name': 'tkinter app'}

base = None

target = Executable(
    script="app.py",
    base=base,
    targetName="app"
    )

    setup(name = "Tkinter Standalone App",
          version = "0.1",
          author = "Me",
          description = "For Testing Purposes Only",
          options = {"bdist_mac": bdist_mac_options},
          executables = [target])
```

**Build Results**

```
python setup.py bdist_mac
```

You can find the build log [here](https://pastebin.com/ybVwGttB). As you can see, it did copy the right *.dylibs but did not include any other files tkinter need. If I comment out the above if condition setting the TCL and TK_LIBRARY paths, launching the app with open -a 'tkinter app.app' or the exectuable within the build/ folder works as expected. However, after uninstalling tcl-tk, I receive this:

```
    brew uninstall tcl-tk

    xcodeclub@XCodeClubs-Mac-4 MacOS % ./app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xcodeclub/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 40, in run
    module.run()
  File "/Users/xcodeclub/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 33, in run
    exec(code,  m.__dict__)
  File "app.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "/Users/xcodeclub/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2261, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.10/lib/tcl8.6 /Users/xcodeclub/.pyenv/lib/tcl8.6 /Users/xcodeclub/lib/tcl8.6 /Users/xcodeclub/.pyenv/library /Users/xcodeclub/library /Users/xcodeclub/tcl8.6.10/library /Users/tcl8.6.10/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

If I copy the missing files to the executable_path, launching the binary file from withing the 'tkinter app.app' folder works:

```
brew install tcl-tk
cp -r /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.10/lib/tk8.6 tkinter\ app.app/Contents/MacOS/
cp -r /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.10/lib/tcl8.6 tkinter\ app.app/Contents/MacOS/
brew uninstall tcl-tk

xcodeclub@XCodeClubs-Mac-4 MacOS % ./app
/Users/xcodeclub/Documents/tkinter-app/build/tkinter app.app/Contents/MacOS/tcl8.6/
/Users/xcodeclub/Documents/tkinter-app/build/tkinter app.app/Contents/MacOS/tk8.6/
```

However, launching the app itself will result in the app opening quickly and then closing, without any error message. Any ideas what I am missing? I have also used to make use of cx-freeze's include_files and include_resources option, but this also didn't work.

I managed to successfully build my tkinter app on Windows and Linux, but I have been stuck with this macOS issues for months. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Same thing here... Did you manage to get it working finally?